# How to add tooltip to a disabled button using ReactStrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have a button which gets enable and disable based on condition, I want to add tooltip to a disable button. Which I am not getting how to do using reactstrap.

```
<Col sm={6}>
                  <Button
                    type="button"
                    id = {`button-${companyId}`}
                    disabled={
                      this.company[companyId] &&
                      this.company[companyId].length
                        ? false
                        : true
                    }
                    title = {this.company[company.id].length < 1? // As a makeover i Used title
                    "Not Active" : ""}
                    style={{ marginLeft: "-16px" }}
                    
                  >
                   </Button>
                    User list
                    {this.company[companyId].length < 1 ? (
                      <UncontrolledTooltip
                        target={`button-${companyId}`}
                        placement="bottom"
                        fade={false}
                      >
                        "Active"
                      </UncontrolledTooltip>
                    ) : null}
                  
                  </Col>
```

But this does not add tooltip to the button. Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use condition like this ;

```
<Button 
color="secondary" 
size="lg" 
disabled={(this.company[companyId] && this.company[companyId].length) ? false: true}>
Button
</Button>
```

Or     `disabled={!(this.company[companyId] && this.company[companyId].length)}>`

Comment: I am not sure but https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/ . here there is nice documentation. I could not see isOpen field in your tooltip check you duble  check tooltip usage.

Comment: I tried this way too, but didn't helped me much. The way I have mentioned worked with fontawesome icon but not working with button.